# Is it ok to create a question to list all the free Magento extension?

Tags: discussion

What I am suggesting is somewhat like this question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com):

[What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

We can add the same type of notice to the question <sub>(it would be a community wiki, not a question)</sub>.

The question would be

> What free extension are there for Magento?

In my opinion, this would be quite helpful for the community to have some sort repository for a list of extension. Where each extension would be its own answer with a link to download it. This way, in time, the more helpful ones would get more upvotes which would bump them to the top.

Comment: Thanks for having the foresight to ask this question about your question in Meta ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely not ok. There are thousands of Magento extensions out there this would be a mess.

[Here](http://packages.firegento.com/) you can find even not a complete list of extensions. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, [there are over 2000 free extensions listed on MagentoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=1&pl=0&te=0&q=&t=1&p=227).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

Q: What free extension are there for Magento?

A:

(basically - but not only links of course)

1. Link / Explanation about to Magento connect
2. Link / Explanation about  to firegento github composer
3. Link / Explanation about  to github search - string "Magento"